# How to reuse port from docker without restarting?

Tags: windows, docker

I'm on a Windows Ten Box, running Docker Version 17.09.0-ce-win33 (13620).

I do something like this. `docker run --rm -p 1001:8787 rocker/rstudio`

however if  quit the docker, and try to rerun it with the same port it fails because its still open. Running netstat its still "listening" on the same port.

```
[vpnkit.exe]
 TCP    [::1]:1001             WN-10DT:0      LISTENING
```

My question is can I reuse the port without having to restart?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "quit the docker"? Please be precise! Also, check `docker ps` vs. `docker ps -a`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt you are correct. docker ps showed that it was still running, I stop it and now it works. Originally I stopped it with ctrl+c however I guess it did not stop it completely.  I forgotten to check.  thanks!

Comment: The `--rm` flag for `docker run` can cause this difference!

Comment: Strange is that on linux it works just fine thus why I did not bother.